# Pagination with no 'page' slug

Tags: pagination

I have pagination on my archieve page - it looks like mysite.com/category/product/page/2. How can I disable/remove 'page' slug? I want it to look like mysite.com/category/product/2.

Thanks in advantage

Comment: I assume no one knows how to do this? This question was asked 3 years ago still no solution posted.